# How do import OpenCV to a JavaFX (non-modular project) on IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Community Edition)?

Tags: opencv, gradle, intellij-idea, javafx, build.gradle

I'm trying out [this](https://github.com/IssacAX123/gmaps-djikstras-shortest-path) project from GitHub.
There isn't much documentation on the developer's part regarding how to setup the project and whatnot.
Googling a way to run the JavaFX app, I understood the way to set it up and get it running is to create a JavaFX app on IntelliJ and copy over the files from that project (from GitHub) to the new project, I was able to copy the files, but I realised I had to import the *opencv* project library, used by many classes in the project.

I Googled again, downloaded *opencv*, added it as a **Global Library**, and restart IntelliJ. But try as I might, the project doesn't sense the presence *opencv*; I've just been bumping into error after error, without progress so far as running the app is in consideration.

I tried adding it to the *build.gradle* file, but my search so far yielded no documentation or instruction regarding setup using **build.gradle**, save [Baeldung's](https://www.baeldung.com/java-opencv); I added the dependency and it pops errors at sync.

Here are screenshots of the setup and errors I'm facing at the moment:

- [opencv listed in external libraries, yet build fails with a "package org.opencv.core does not exist" error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnoR3.png)
- [opencv added as global variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIKTe.png)
- [opencv added to project in **Modules**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyAbN.png)

OpenCV disappears from Modules in Project Structure, and I have to re-add it sometimes.

I'm using:

- Windows 10 (21H2 build 19044.1766)
- on an 8 GB DDR3L RAM, 1 TB HDD, x64 PC.
- The project is configured to run with JDK 14,
- and JavaFX openjfx-14.0.2.1_windows-x64_bin-sdk.
- OpenCV version opencv-4.6.0-vc14_vc15.

Stack Trace:

```
21:46:27: Executing ':Main.main()'...


> Configure project :
Project : => no module-info.java found

> Task :compileJava
C:\Users\mich\IdeaProjects\DjikstraAlgo\src\main\java\org\openjfx\djikstraalgo\Algorithm\ConvertToArray.java:4: error: package org.opencv.core does not exist
import org.opencv.core.Core;
                  ^
C:\Users\mich\IdeaProjects\DjikstraAlgo\src\main\java\org\openjfx\djikstraalgo\Algorithm\ConvertToArray.java:5: error: package org.opencv.core does not exist
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
                  ^
C:\Users\mich\IdeaProjects\DjikstraAlgo\src\main\java\org\openjfx\djikstraalgo\Algorithm\ConvertToArray.java:6: error: package org.opencv.imgcodecs does not exist
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
                       ^
C:\Users\mich\IdeaProjects\DjikstraAlgo\src\main\java\org\openjfx\djikstraalgo\Algorithm\ConvertToArray.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    Mat img;
    ^
  symbol:   class Mat
  location: class ConvertToArray
C:\Users\mich\IdeaProjects\DjikstraAlgo\src\main\java\org\openjfx\djikstraalgo\Algorithm\ConvertToArray.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    public Mat getMatrix(){
       ^
  symbol:   class Mat
  location: class ConvertToArray
C:\Users\mich\IdeaProjects\DjikstraAlgo\src\main\java\org\openjfx\djikstraalgo\Algorithm\Djikstra.java:7: error: package org.opencv.core does not exist
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
                  ^
C:\Users\mich\IdeaProjects\DjikstraAlgo\src\main\java\org\openjfx\djikstraalgo\Algorithm\Djikstra.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    Mat img;
    ^
  symbol:   class Mat
  location: class Djikstra
C:\Users\mich\IdeaProjects\DjikstraAlgo\src\main\java\org\openjfx\djikstraalgo\Algorithm\Djikstra.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    public Djikstra(Mat img, int[] source, int[] sink){
                ^
  symbol:   class Mat
  location: class Djikstra
C:\Users\mich\IdeaProjects\DjikstraAlgo\src\main\java\org\openjfx\djikstraalgo\Controller.java:19: error: package org.opencv.core does not exist
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
                  ^
C:\Users\mich\IdeaProjects\DjikstraAlgo\src\main\java\org\openjfx\djikstraalgo\Algorithm\ConvertToArray.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        img = Imgcodecs.imread(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\images\\" +filepath);
          ^
  symbol:   variable Imgcodecs
  location: class ConvertToArray
C:\Users\mich\IdeaProjects\DjikstraAlgo\src\main\java\org\openjfx\djikstraalgo\Controller.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
        Mat img = img_grid.getMatrix();
        ^
  symbol:   class Mat
  location: class Controller
11 errors

> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
1 actionable task: 1 executed
21:46:38: Execution finished ':Main.main()'.
```

Comment: Please provide a stack trace generated by a failure when you run the app as well as the full command line Idea is using for the execution.  Place them in your question as text formatted as code.  Include full info of al versions used, OS, jdk, JavaFX, opencv, hardware.  Ensure you can run a simple hello world JavaFX app in your environment without opencv.

Comment: I tried using opencv from a JavaFX app (modular), but had to manually extract and load the native library for it to be accessible as well as add require opencv as an automatic module.  I used the most recent opencv version 4.5.1-2 as well as JDK 18.0.1 and JavaFX 18.0.1.  I manually extracted the native binary from the jar and copied it to a known path, then manually loaded it with a System.load command in the app main method.  I don't know why the built-in loader in opencv did not load the native lib it extracts from the jar on startup, but manual setup seemed to work.

Comment: The built-in [opencv native library extractor and loading code](https://github.com/openpnp/opencv/blob/develop/src/main/java/nu/pattern/OpenCV.java#L356).  Note that the only mac binary is x86, so if you have a newer mac with an M1 or M2 chip, it won't currently work.  There is no native library provided by opencv for M1 architecture under OS X, there is one for Linux and perhaps it can be ported for use but I don't know about that, you could research it if you need it.

Comment: @jewelsea, I'm using Windows 10 (21H2 build 19044.1766) on an 8 GB _DDR3L RAM_, 1 TB HDD, x64 PC. 
The project is configured to run with *JDK 14*, and **JavaFX** _openjfx-14.0.2.1_windows-x64_bin-sdk_.
*OpenCV* version _opencv-4.6.0-vc14_vc15_.

Comment: Try manually extracting the opencv dll from the opencv jar and placing it on a known directory, then adding the line: System.load("<opencv dll absolute file name>"); as the first statement in your application `main` method.

Comment: I saw something on adding ```opencv``` locally by copying the libraries, just as I did to initialise the project by copying its files to a working JavaFX ```HelloApplication```, but it seemed cumbersome.
I added ```JavaFX```'s _openjfx_ via```Project Structure> Libraries```, and it's the only tagged **problem** (just a warning, I think). I'll remove it later, see how things turn out.

Comment: I do not understand your last comment.  You can edit the question to add more information instead of commenting.  Sometimes that is more helpful.

Comment: First or second sentence (as delimited by **.**)?

Comment: The bit that says "it's the only tagged problem (just a warning, I think)", I don't know what that means.  Also I don't know which opencv libraries you are referring to, the jar files or the native libraries with native code or where you were copying them to.  Perhaps your answer clarifies some of my misunderstanding (I assume your setup works for you now).

Comment: I'm referring to `opencv` library from extracted jar file; could the library be extracted from dll file too?

Comment: The _problem_ from [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIKTe.png); I didn't upload it, because it's the least of my concerns. And yes, setup works now. The issue presented in this thread is resolved; what remains is - API upgrade - without the context of this thread.

Comment: "could the library be extracted from dll file too?" -> no a DLL is a library (the name is short for Dynamically Linked Library).  A DLL is a native library.  A JAR is a java archive, traditionally java code, generally for libraries and applications with associated resources.  opencv packs the dynamic libraries in its jar file so you can extract them from there (which I guess is what you did).  The extraction is supposed to be automatic without user intervention but that didn't appear to work in my or your setup (perhaps the auto extraction is for Java 8, not Java 9+).

Answer (score 2):

Part of the hits I dug online was an addition to `build.gradle`:

```
compile fileTree(dir:'path:\\to\\opencv\\lib\\', includes: ['*jar'])
```

I was using

```
implementation fileTree(dir:'D:\\...\\opencv-4.6.0-vc14_vc15\\build\\java\\x64\\', includes: ['*jar'])
```

which has the `opencv_java460` file.

**Removing `64\\` part solved it. I'm using

```
implementation fileTree(dir:'D:\\...\\opencv-4.6.0-vc14_vc15\\build\\java\\', includes: ['*jar'])
```

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA would have saved me time, if it imported from [the `iml` file](https://github.com/IssacAX123/gmaps-djikstras-shortest-path/blob/master/gmaps-djikstras-shortest-path.iml). I used `opencv` *4.6.0* instead of *4.5.3* used in project. Ah, documentation...!

Comment: I think that I understand better now what happened.  You manually extracted the native libraries and then specified the path to the native libraries to Idea (via gradle). Initially you provided the wrong path to the extracted native libraries and the Java runtime couldn't find them.  After you fixed the path for the native libraries, they could be found.  For my setup, I manually extracted the libraries. I then explicitly loaded the appropriate library via System.load, effectively accomplishing the same thing (correct resolution of the native library path) as your revised setup.

Comment: This could (perhaps) be simplified if opencv used [Java Platform modules that allow the embedding of native code](https://openjdk.org/projects/jigsaw/doc/topics/nativecode.html), similar to how JavaFX works.  Though, from the number of issues that users have with the JavaFX module setup, there would still probably be issues that people would encounter when using such opencv modules if they existed.

Comment: I didn't manually extract the libraries though

Comment: Oh, ok, I guess what happened then is that when you fixed the path in gradle, the library itself was able to automatically extract the native libraries and access them when it was used using the [built-in extraction and auto-loading code](https://github.com/openpnp/opencv/blob/develop/src/main/java/nu/pattern/OpenCV.java#L356) which failed in my environment.

Comment: Yeah... I guess so. Nothing definite at the moment.